# Array field referenced to another class Array filed doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have

```
class A{
  users = new B().users;
}

class B{
  users : Array<any> = [];
}
```

at the first run the users fields are the same in both classes , but when users in class B changed the users in A isn't changed .
example : at first A.users and B.users are [user1]
when I add new user to B.users ([user1, user2]) A.users still the same .
Any idea ?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea

Depends on how you add them. If you are doing something like `b.users = b.users.concat([another]);` then `b.users` *will be a new array* distict from the one that is referenced by A.

**NOTE:** Having two classes point the same array seems like a bad idea where mutation will quickly get out of hand and you will not know *what moved your cheese*. But there isn't more architecture advice I can give without a larger context that you can present in a separate question if you want.

Comment: Actually A is my Ui view model , and users inside it is binded to the view HTML list . B holds the users array and encapsulate all its logic.

Comment: @Wasim sounds okay then